# execute query result statements

Tags: mysql, procedure, concatenation

I've got a set of tables named results_%, all with the same structure.

I would like to add a index to this tables.

I can get the alter statement for each table as a row of a select query result but I don't know how to execute this statements:

```
select concat( 'alter table ', test_db.table_name, ' add index `did` (`did`);' ) as statement 
from information_schema.tables test_db 
where test_db.table_name like 'results_%';
```

What am I missing?

The ouput (which I would like to execute instead of just have it displayed to me):

```
+---------------------------------------------------------+
| statement                                               |
+---------------------------------------------------------+
| alter table results_Em7777_spa add index `did` (`did`); |
| alter table results_KaEng_eng add index `did` (`did`);  |
| alter table results_Ka_spa add index `did` (`did`);     |
| alter table results_Mc_spa add index `did` (`did`);     |
| alter table results_Mo_eng add index `did` (`did`);     |
| alter table results_Pe_eng add index `did` (`did`);     |
| alter table results_SU_spa add index `did` (`did`);     |
| alter table results_Ta_spa add index `did` (`did`);     |
| alter table results_ba_eng add index `did` (`did`);     |
| alter table results_br_eng add index `did` (`did`);     |
| alter table results_ca_spa add index `did` (`did`);     |
| alter table results_ch_spa add index `did` (`did`);     |
| alter table results_da_spa add index `did` (`did`);     |
| alter table results_ga_eng add index `did` (`did`);     |
| alter table results_ge_spa add index `did` (`did`);     |
| alter table results_gk_eng add index `did` (`did`);     |
+---------------------------------------------------------+
16 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

[EDIT]

I tried:

```
drop procedure if exists altlike; 
delimiter // 
create procedure altlike() 
begin 
   set group_concat_max_len = 65535; 
   select @altrlk:= concat( 'alter table ', test_db.table_name , ' add index `did` (`did`);' )
   from information_schema.tables test_db
   where test_db.table_name like "results_%"; 
   prepare statement from @altrlk; 
   execute statement; 
end // 
delimiter ; 
call altlike();
```

But still no luck: It only alters the last matched table (results_gk_eng).

Comment: You could try PREPARE/EXECUTE: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html

Comment: I also thought that'd be the idea but after reading the documentation I still can't figure out how to use them for this.

Comment: What's the issue? Write a procedure that iterates over the result set and executes it line by line

Comment: I even tried without luck: drop procedure if exists altlike;
delimiter //
create procedure altlike(pattern varchar(128))
begin
  set group_concat_max_len = 65535;
  select @altrlk:= concat( 'alter table ', test_db.table_name , ' add index `did` (`did`);' ) from information_schema.tables where test_db.table_name like pattern;
  prepare statement from @altrlk;
  execute statement;
end //
delimiter ;
call altlike("results_%");

Comment: (Ok I'll add it to the question so it's more clear to read)

Comment: `@altrlk:= concat(...` syntax is sooooooooooo wrong. You need to start from very basics about how to use cursors http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/cursors.html

Comment: Reading it. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You basically printing out lines of string out of the DB, it would not automatically execute it just because it looks like a sql statement;

What you can do is either use a programming language to execute line by line as you get the results back.

Or throw this into a stored procedure where it feed a secondary block of execution.

Example: FROM http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/an-introduction-to-stored-procedures/ read more about it.

```
DELIMITER //  

CREATE PROCEDURE `proc_CURSOR` (OUT param1 INT)  
BEGIN  
    DECLARE a, b, c INT;  
    DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR SELECT col1 FROM table1;  
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET b = 1;  
    OPEN cur1;  

    SET b = 0;  
    SET c = 0;  

    WHILE b = 0 DO  
        FETCH cur1 INTO a;  
        IF b = 0 THEN  
            SET c = c + a;  
    END IF;  
    END WHILE;  

    CLOSE cur1;  
    SET param1 = c;  

END //
```

Comment: I know, I would like to know if there is a way of telling mysql to execute this output, like a mysql procedure, without recurring to an external script.

Comment: Another not an answer at all :-S

Comment: @zerkms I do believe this is what you wrote as a comment "What's the issue? Write a procedure that iterates over the result set and executes it line by line" and if you actual read the code, it does exactly that, with the exception that it is not exactly the alter statement, but I am not here to do his work, but point him to the right direction.

Comment: @Churk: the question was "how to execute a string as a query" not "how to write basic SP". The answer doesn't shed any light to the real question. OP doesn't know how to execute dynamically query, but **does know** how to write SPs. So, I don't know how your copy-pasted SP could help

Comment: Probably you was partially right, and OP doesn't know how to use cursors, sorry ;-)

Comment: Any solution involving just SQL would work for me. It's the first time I try pointers or using a MySQL procedure, and right now I can only get it to work for the last matched column, as I pointed out in my last edit of the question, don't know why but as @zerkms says my syntax knowledge needs improvement. Looking at the tutorial you  linked me.

Comment: @elcodedocle: you iterate over result set and execute the command line by line. I'm sure it is easy to do... :-)

Comment: I finally got it. I must say, it would take me like 2 mins top to just do it using a php script instead but anyway I guess had to learn the basics abouts SP and cursors someday... Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 4):

```
drop procedure if exists `altlike`; 
DELIMITER // 
CREATE PROCEDURE `altlike` ()  
BEGIN
  DECLARE a,c VARCHAR(256);  
  DECLARE b INT;  
  DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR select concat(test_db.table_name)
  from information_schema.tables test_db 
  where test_db.table_name like 'results_%';
  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET b = 1;
  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR 1061 SET b = 0;  
  OPEN cur1;  
  SET b = 0;    
  WHILE b = 0 DO  
    FETCH cur1 INTO a;  
    IF b = 0 THEN
      SET @c = concat ('ALTER IGNORE TABLE `', a, '` ADD INDEX `did` (`did`)');
      PREPARE stmt1 FROM @c;
      EXECUTE stmt1; 
      DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1; 
    END IF;  
  END WHILE;  
  CLOSE cur1;       
END //  
call altlike();
```

Comment: This should be the correct answer as it answers OPs question